# Vue.js Loading and hiding async component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am making a chatbot in vue.js and I need your help. I created 2 Vue components:

- **ChatLoader.vue** - first components that render a button to open actual webchat window
- **Webchat.vue** - the async component that only loads when I
  Click on a button to open the chat window.

So what my **ChatLoader.vue** is doing is setting parameter **chatInitialized = true** on button click. Then the chat window is opened.

In my **Webchat.vue** I have a close button which on click only hides the chat window (not removed from DOM) by setting **showWindow = false;**

Now when the chat window is hidden I again see the button to open the chat (which was there all the time only not visible because overlapped by chatwindow) but when I click on the button now I want to set showWindow = true in Webchat.vue component instead of the previous behavior, so the webchat window is shown again.

ChatLoading.vue:

```
    <template>
    <div>
        <span class="open-chat" v-on:click="showChat">
            <i class="icon ficon-live-chat"></i>
            Virtual assistant
        </span>
        <Webchat v-if="chatInitialized"></Webchat>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import ChatLoading from "./ChatLoading.vue";

    const Webchat = () => ({
        component: import('./Webchat.vue'),
        loading: ChatLoading
    });

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                chatInitialized: false
            }
        },
        components: {
            Webchat
        },
        methods: {
            showChat() {
                this.chatInitialized = true;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Webchat.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="chat-window" v-show="showWindow">
        <button type="button" class="cancel icon ficon-close" v-on:click="minimize"></button>
        <WebchatPlugin
        >
        </<WebchatPlugin>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import <WebchatPlugin{
        createDirectLine,
        createStore
    } from "botframework-webchat/lib/index";
    import {DirectLine} from "botframework-directlinejs";

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                showWindow : true
            }
        },
        components: <WebchatPlugin
        methods: {
            minimize() {
                this.showWindow = false
            }
        },
</script>
```

How can I accomplish that? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to toggle the child component's (`<Webchat>`) state `showWindow` from a consuming parent component, then you will have to create a method in the child component that can be invoked by the parent element.

First of all, in your `Webchat` component, create a new method, say `maximize`, that will change `this.showWindow` to `true`:

```
methods: {
    minimize() {
        this.showWindow = false;
    },
    maximize() {
        this.showWindow = true;
    }
},
```

---

Then, in your parent component, you can then:

1. Create a reference to your `Webchat` component
2. Use `this.$ref` to access the component and its inner methods, and call the `maximize()` method you've just created:

Example:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <span class="open-chat" v-on:click="showChat">
            <i class="icon ficon-live-chat"></i>
            Virtual assistant
        </span>

        <!-- Use `ref` attribute to create a reference to component -->
        <Webchat ref="webchat" v-if="chatInitialized"></Webchat>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import ChatLoading from "./ChatLoading.vue";

    const Webchat = () => ({
        component: import('./Webchat.vue'),
        loading: ChatLoading
    });

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                chatInitialized: false
            }
        },
        components: {
            Webchat
        },
        methods: {
            showChat() {
                this.chatInitialized = true;

                // Access Webchat component's inner method
                // Do this inside `this.$nextTick` to ensure it is accessible
                this.$nextTick(() => {
                    this.$refs.webchat.maximize();
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You beat me to it - however I think you may have an issue - you are calling maximize() when the child component may not yet have been created.  You might need to do this conditionally only if the chat is already initialised.

Comment: @EuanSmith True that, let me update my answer. Probably makes sense to wrap it inside `this.$nextTick()`

Comment: @Terry thanks, that solved my issue! Didn't know about $refs property in vue.js yet.